# C# type conversion?

Tags: c#

```
public static Series MeterReadingsToPieChart(IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, double>> readings)
{
    object[] points = ? // I dont know how can I create this array from readings.

    Series series = new Series
    {
        Type = ChartTypes.Pie,
        Name = "",
        Data = new Data(points)
    };

    return series;
}
```

I want to create the following dynamically from the above code

```
Series series = new Series
{
    Type = ChartTypes.Pie,
    Name = "",
    Data = new Data(new object[]
           {
               new object[] { "Gaziemir", 45.0 },
               new object[] { "Bornova", 26.8 },
               new object[] { "Forum Bornova", 8.5 }
           })
};
```

Could you show a starting point?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match the code at the bottom, that would be:

```
object[][] points = readings.Select(
      pair => new object[] { pair.Key, pair.Value }).ToArray();

Series series = new Series
{
    Type = ChartTypes.Pie,
    Name = "",
    Data = new Data(points))
};
```

However, personally I would say that an `object[][]` is not the best option here...